# Xcode chat app, creating dynamic views - a little lost

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification

Am just about to start doing an iphone application which is supposed to have a multi user private chat. Something like facebook style, where the user has a list of friends and he can chat with them independently. I just need a little direction here

1. If i have a list of users, let's say i create individual views for the chat, how can I handle these views? If jim is chatting with dick and jane, there should be 2 views, each for one chat window right? Are there any references that i can use.
2. I am looking for references in socket programming where i can push messages to the user from the server. I have been looking but could not find anything helpful.
3. If i try to update the user's chat window using local notifications, lets say request data every couple of seconds, will that be battery draining?

I would really like some direction here, i do not want to start something just realize its the wrong way.

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Those all sound like design decisions. For example, do you want to display each user's messages in a separate view? That's entirely up to you.
2. You'll want to read about [iOS Push Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html).
3. If you mean that you intend to poll some server for updates, then yes, that will use a lot of battery. This is exactly the sort of situation that the push notification system was created to help you avoid.

Comment: Yeah, i am actually thinking of the app, have'nt started it. Was looking for the right directions.
I have worked with push notifications before, but not sure if they can be used in a scenario like a chat, cause push notifications dont guarantee any deliver time, right?