# When will a autorelease get released

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, autorelease

I am looking to to develop an app where there will be "n" number of views created based on the user's interaction. If each of these views are created dynamically with autorelease, when will the view actually be released?

Lets say there are 10 views, all being dynamically created views with autorelease:

1. View 1 is created and added to a navigation stack, user is shown view 1
2. User moves to another view "View 2", View 1 is pushed off the stack and View 2 is added. Will View 1 be released here? I would not want it to be released, so should i retain it?
3. The problem is, i might not know how many views i am creating, so deallocating them manually might be problem, or is there a way?

I am a little confused soul here.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't add views to navigation stack, you add view controllers.
2. When you push view controller 2, the 1st one will not get released, no. Navigation controller will always keep all it's view controllers retained until they are popped off the stack. It will only call -unloadView on non-displayed view controllers to free up some memory, but if you are creating your views inside view controllers' loadView method, everything will get recreated automatically.
3. You don't dealloc anything manually, you can only release it. Since navigation controller will retain any view controller you add on it's stack, you are free to release it yourself.

From the way you ask your questions, I've noticed you are missing some very basic knowledge about iOS SDK, MVC and OOP in general. I would honestly suggest you try creating a much simpler app than [that chat app of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232693/xcode-chat-app-creating-dynamic-views-a-little-lost) first to learn some basics.

Comment: HI fichek, am sorry, i did mean to say view controller and release (sorry i used the word dealloc) - still getting used to the IOS jargon. I am of course doing my part and learning, at the same time i was hoping experts like you could help me in the process of learning. I could not find any documentation on how the view controllers get released inside a navigation stack, hence i asked it here. Can you point me to some resources?

Comment: That's what StackOverflow is for ;) Have you seen CS193P videos on iTunes U? They are the best iOS development resource I could ever suggest to anyone.

Comment: Thanks, i am looking at those videos. I undertsand, a view controller is released when you pop it off the navigation stack, how can i retain it without being released?

Comment: Once you alloc/init a view controller (or an instance of any other class for that matter), it has retainCount of 1. Usually when you pass that instance to something (like adding a view to another view, or adding view controller to navigation stack, or adding any object to array) it automatically gets retained by that object if needed, and released when it's no longer needed (view removed, controller popped, object removed from array...). So whoever created that object  can release it after passing it to other object unless it needs the object later.

Comment: In that case you can release it whenever you no longer need it. You usually create an instance variable or property for such objects and release them inside dealloc method.

Answer (score 1):

It will help if you post key segments of your code so we can see what you are doing.  In short, if a view controller is in the navigation stack, it will be retained by the navigation controller.  If it is popped off but you want to keep it, you'll need to retain it from another controller, probably the one that presents it.

Comment: Hi peter, i did'tn even write a single line of code, am just trying to find answers for questions so that i wont start in a weird direction. Am just looking for resources that would help me learn a few things before i jump into the app

Comment: Cool.  My advice: jump in and break things.  Thats how the best programmers learn, and then you'll be able to ask specific questions that you'll get great answers for.

Comment: That's what am trying to do Peter, am still new to IOS, getting used to how things work in IOS :)